# EMF - Radiation Pattern

Tags: effects

how to render a radiation pattern like following with blender?

[image]

Here a short video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzdsl56rnbgjpzf/iFlexio_StaticImage_VFX_Test_1.mov?dl=0

Thanks for your support.

LS

Comment: There are too many ways of doing this, but probably the best solution is to do it in the compositor.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: @cegaton It is a movie file... so he'd need to turn it into a gif. That is not trivial.

Comment: Hi guys, anyone who could provide a template to work with?